# Timing within a CSS Image Slider

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe

I am having an issue with timing within a CSS keyframe animation.

I have it 90% there, but am having a gap between each image on appearance.

I know this is a timing issue, but I can't for the life of me get the gap to disappear without breaking the current functionality.

Code so far:

```css
.slider {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  background: gray;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.slide,
.slide img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.slide h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  right: 0;
  height: 10%;
  color: white;
}
.slide p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 0;
  height: 60%;
  color: white;
}
.slide {
  transform: translateX(100%);
  -webkit-animation: slide 20s forwards infinite;
}
.slide:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
}
.slide:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 10s;
}
.slide:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 15s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes slide {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  5% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  20% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200" />
    <h1>Slide 1</h1>

    <p>Text to do with slide 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/400" />
    <h1>Slide 2</h1>

    <p>Text to do with slide 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/800" />
    <h1>Slide 3</h1>

    <p>Text to do with slide 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1800/1200" />
    <h1>Slide 4</h1>

    <p>Text to do with slide 4</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

In my snippet, you can see a short delay which allows the grey background to appear before the next image.

My design will **only cater for 4 images**,which should be on screen for around 5 seconds each. I'm happy to stay with CSS keyframes for this (not jquery or external plugins).

Please note I've removed prefixes so will currently support the `webkit` prefix.

Could someone please explain how I should be timing this? I'm pretty sure it's this 0% -> 5% transition, but I can't be sure?

any assistance here would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix is to make each image stay on screen (in a fixed state or a slide in/out state) for 1/4th of the animation's duration. Considering that for the first 5% it is sliding in and for the last 5% it is sliding out, we have to set the slide out to be between 25% and 30% like the below snippet.

```css
.slider {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  background: gray;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slide,
.slide img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.slide h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  right: 0;
  height: 10%;
  color: white;
}
.slide p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 0;
  height: 60%;
  color: white;
}
.slide {
    transform: translateX(100%);
 -webkit-animation: slide 20s infinite linear;
}
.slide:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
}
.slide:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 10s;
}
.slide:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 15s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes slide {
  5% {
    transform: translateX(0); /* 1s 6s 11s 16s */
  }
  25% {
    transform: translateX(0); /* 5s 10s 14s 19s */
  }
  30% {
    transform: translateX(-100%); /* 6s 11s 16s 20s */
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }    
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200" />
    <h1>Slide 1</h1>

    <p>Text to do with slide 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/400" />
    <h1>Slide 2</h1>

    <p>Text to do with slide 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/800" />
    <h1>Slide 3</h1>

    <p>Text to do with slide 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1800/1200" />
    <h1>Slide 4</h1>

    <p>Text to do with slide 4</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a ghant-like chart in order to work what was happening, and ended up altering my keyframe animation. I also added a fifth image set in order to keep to whole seconds.

I ended up with:

```css
.slider {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  background: gray;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slide,
.slide img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
}
.slide {
  transform: translateX(100%);
  -webkit-animation: slide 50s ease-in-out 0s infinite;
}
.slide h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  right: 0;
  height: 10%;
  color: white;
}
.slide p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 0;
  height: 60%;
  color: white;
}
.slide:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 10s;
}
.slide:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 20s;
}
.slide:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 30s;
}
.slide:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 40s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes slide {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  2% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  20% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  22% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1800/1200" />
    <h1>Slide 1</h1>
    <p>Text to do with slide 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1000/500" />
    <h1>Slide 2</h1>
    <p>Text to do with slide 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100" />
    <h1>Slide 3</h1>
    <p>Text to do with slide 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/400" />
    <h1>Slide 4</h1>
    <p>Text to do with slide 4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/800" />
    <h1>Slide 5</h1>
    <p>Text to do with slide 5</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This allowed me to keep the animation smooth between transitions, and also allowed me to have enough time in order for the user to read the contents of the slide.

---

this functionality also allowed me to use animation-play-state to pause the slider when hovering it :)

```
.slider:hover .slide{
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
}
```