# Css slider keyframe end of the loop shows blank page

Tags: html, css, keyframe

I am having some issues with the slider i made using CSS. I have 2 images and i am trying to slide left. At the end of the second image, it should go first but instead shows blank slide. I think there is a problem with the keyframe percentage, not sure yet?

How do i calculate the keyframes for 2 sliding images?

```
<div id="captioned-gallery">
    <figure class="slider">
        <figure>
            <img src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/cyprus-nicosia-2.jpg" alt>
            <figcaption>slider 1 caption</figcaption>
        </figure>

        <figure>
            <img src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/nicosia.jpg" alt>
            <figcaption> slider 2 caption</figcaption>
        </figure>

    </figure>
</div>
```

and CSS

```
/* Frontpage Slider */

@keyframes slidy {
    0% {
        left: 0%;
    }
    50% {
        left: -100%;
    }
    75% {
        left: -200%;
    }
    100% {
        left: -200%;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slidy {
    0% {
        left: 0%;
    }
    50% {
        left: -100%;
    }
    75% {
        left: -200%;
    }
    100% {
        left: -200%;
    }
}

figure {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
}

div#captioned-gallery {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

figure.slider {
    position: relative;
    width: 200%;
    font-size: 0;
    animation: 25s slidy infinite;
    -webkit-animation: 20s slidy infinite
}

figure.slider figure {
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    position: inherit;
}

figure.slider img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

figure.slider figure figcaption {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 10%;
    width: 75%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 160%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 3vw;
    padding: .6rem;
}
```

Comment: No need for so many stops. Just use the `translate` to move the slides from 0 to 100%. Also what's with those nested figures? See here - http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/0z9z36jh/1/

Comment: Are you looking for a cyclic slider? That is, it slides from 1 to 2 and then slides back to 1 (or) just for slide 1 to appear once the animation has reached its end for each loop? Cyclic animation is tough but the other alternate is rather easy to achieve.

Comment: Yes cyclic or perhaps any slider is okay as long as there is no blank slider

Comment: @pbu: In that case you could have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30329838/timing-within-a-css-image-slider/30331598#30331598) as it produces a similar image slider. If you are happy with that answer then I'll mark this as duplicate (or) if that doesn't help you fully then [edit] in more information into the question.

Answer (score 1):

There is much wrong there, have a look here.

```
<div id="captioned-gallery">
<div class="slider">
```

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/PPEXgq

I could not fix the absolutely positioned figcaption though, I have no idea why, but am bit in a hurry. If someone can fox that meanwhile.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this code worked for me to run 2 slides cyclic. The trick is to slow down the transition of the 2nd slide, so that when it finishes it cycles to first slide.

```
@keyframes slidy {
0% { left: 0%; }
50% { left: -100%; }
100% { left: -200%; }
}


@-webkit-keyframes slidy {
0% { left: 0%; }
50% { left: -100%; }
100% { left: -200%; }
}
```